# LaTeX not compiling after switching computer

Tags: installing, compiling, texworks, texniccenter, auxiliary-files

I've changed computers recently; my project was compiling just fine previously, and on the new computer it's not compiling at all. The output is stuck at the last version I compiled on the previous computer (2015/03/04; today is 2015/04/07).

I had installed Texlive on the old pc, I was working on TeXnic Center and compiling with XeLaTeX. I've installed Texlive on the new pc, and I've re-installed separately MikTeX and GSview, but maybe I'm still missing some software? Since the project used to compile fine, I don't think the code is bad but here's my preamble just in case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[Latin,Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Kokila}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Kokila}
\newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
```

UPDATE: SOLVED{*When I compile in TeXnic Center there is no error message, the only problem is that the output generated is the 2015/03/04 version. Yet no LaTeX file on this computer is from 2015/03/04, they're all up to date. I don't even understand where LaTeX gets this 2015/03/04 version from. 
I've cleaned all the aux and log files with the "clean project" option then re-run TeXnic Center several times; but then TeXnic Center "couldn't find thefile.aux", it didn't generate a new one by itself. So I compiled the code written with TeXnic Center in TeXworks. It compiles fine for a bit, then ends with this message: 
    ! File ended while scanning use of \emph .
     
                    \par 
    l.101 \input{ThesisIIA1}
Now again, TIME WARP: there was indeed an missing accolade with \emph in this file, but I corrected it and deleted all the files where the error was present. TeXworks doesn't seem to acknowledge this correction. 
So I'm stuck with TeXnic Center that doesn't generate a new .aux file, and TeXworks that doesn't find the path to the corrected file... Please help!*}

PS: both computers are running Windows 7. The old computer is dead. The new one is enabled to install packages on-the-fly. In case you wondered =)

UPDATE: after solving a code error it's compiling fine on Texworks now, but not at all anymore on TeXnic Center. Here's the latest lines on my log (I put [path] for the path):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xetex 2015.4.7)  8 APR 2015 11:11
entering extended mode
**Thesis.tex

("[path]\LaTeX\Thesis.tex"
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  [a4paper,12pt]{book}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \usepackage
               {amsfonts}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \usepackage
               {amssymb}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Same for each and every package... Packages that all were summoned just fine yesterday. Sigh. So the question now is: where do I check if all packages are called in properly by TeXnic Center?

Comment: Can you compile a simple hello world file. \documentclass{article}\begin{article}Hello World\end{document}.  You error message from Texworks probably means you are missing an end group somewhere. Probably at the location of \emph

Comment: `! File ended while scanning use of \emph .`  implies that there is a missing `}` so you have `\emph{... rest of file` without evidence to the contrary I'd assume that is the case, and the error message is correct.

Comment: Your description is not entirely clear. Why not delete all files but the `.tex` file and start over? Why not try compiling from a command terminal? if neither of those help, then post a *complete but minimal* `.tex` file that shows the problem; in your case you might also want to post the `.log` as well.

Comment: @R. Schumacher: with Texworks yes, with TeXnic Center no. Bibtex says "I couldn't open file name test.aux" and MakeIndex says "Input index file test.idx not found".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: yes thank you, indeed I had missed on a missing }. Now Texworks is compiling fine. But TeXnic Center is not even compiling an outdated version anymore, it fails and says "undefined control sequence" for every line in the preamble.

Comment: @jon: I have deleted all files but the .aux, including the log. When I compile with TeXnic Center it fails and warns that the log has been modified outside TeXnic Center. It asks if I want to reload the log, I hit Yes, nothing happens. Compiling from a command terminal works but I would like to be able to use TeXnic Center like before, it's just way more convenient.

Comment: @Pucklib I would guess your editor is set up to use plain tex instead of latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean for compiling? It is set on XeLaTex to PDF. If you mean something else please explain, I'm a noob!

Comment: you are not giving enough information (and I have never used texnic center) but the most common reason for tex giving undefined command errors for latex preamble commands is that tex is being used instead of latex. and I just see you added your log file which confirms that is the case here `(preloaded format=xetex `  preloaded format is xetex not xelatex, so you are using xetex not xelatex

Answer (score 2):

Please do not edit the question to ask unrelated questions, it makes the site impossible to follow later, open a new question for new questions.

The original problem was exactly as indicated by TeX, a missing `}` meant that the argument for `\emph{....` was not closed before the end of file.

The new problem is that LaTeX commands like `\documentclass` are not defined as you are using xetex (plain TeX) not xelatex (LaTeX).